# 403 error in Node Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node App where there is a page which posts their email address to login to the app (I'm not doing anything but storing the email address for now). When I push the app to production it works fine for a little while and then I start getting a 403 error like this:

```
Express
403 Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
at /opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:54:7
at Object.ondone (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/uid2/index.js:46:8)
```

This is what I'm seeing in the log:

```
err Sun, 09 Mar 2014 11:52:01 GMT Error: Forbidden
at Object.exports.error (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils.js:63:13)
at createToken (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:82:55)
at /opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/csrf.js:54:7
at Object.ondone (/opt/run/snapshot/package/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/node_modules/uid2/index.js:46:8)
```

If I restart the app without any code changes, login starts working again. I'm guessing something to do with csrf is going stale. I definitely am passing a csrf token on the login page. I can see it when I do a view source.

I'm on node 0.10, I'm wondering if I should go back to 0.8.

here's my config:

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine','ejs');
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(helmet.xframe());
    app.use(helmet.iexss());
    app.use(helmet.contentTypeOptions());
    app.use(helmet.cacheControl());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: "**********************",
        cookie: {
            maxAge  : 3600000, //1 hours
            expires : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000), //2 Hours
        },

        store: new MongoStore({
            mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection
         })
        })
    );

    //app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:"fooseball123!"}));
    app.use(express.csrf());
    //middleware to make csrf token available 
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        //res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
        res.locals.token = req.csrfToken();
        next();
      });
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge: 86400000}));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did two things and it looks like they fixed the issue.

1. I rolled my node version back to 0.8
2. I removed the cookie parameter inside the call to express.session.

I'm guessing the issue has something to do with #2.

I don't know what this has to do with the csrf errors I was getting.

Comment: For me the problem was with the Mongo store, session data wasn't being stored to MongoDB so there was nothing to validate the csrf value against as the session was empty

Comment: I definitely was seeing the session information in the store. I believe the issue was that the cookie value was being set to two hours from the time the application started, so after that it was always expired.